# QWebEngineView crashes without error output

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5, qwebengineview

The page loads, I enter something in the search and the application freezes dead. You can have time to click on some link, but then everything freezes and crashes. There is no error message.
The most interesting thing is that it used to work, and then after some point it stopped (the code did NOT change).

my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

class TabWidget(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QTabWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        url = QUrl("https://google.com")
        view = HtmlView(self)
        view.load(url)
        ix = self.addTab(view, "loading ...")

class HtmlView(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWebEngineView.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.tab = self.parent()

    def createWindow(self, windowType):
        if windowType == QWebEnginePage.WebBrowserTab:
            webView = HtmlView(self.tab)
            ix = self.tab.addTab(webView, "loading ...")
            self.tab.setCurrentIndex(ix)
            return webView
        return QWebEngineView.createWindow(self, windowType)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = TabWidget()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I checked the drivers, reinstalled PyQt, but it doesn't help.
I use Windows 10 and Python 3.9.7. MinGW write "Segmentation fault
", when app crashed

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem using qt-5.15.8 and pyqt-5.15.9 on linux.

Comment: I use Windows 10